how to hide ingored-files combo/tree from local changes in git tab in idea?
My idea got crazy and stop showing Log tab contents in for GIT. Nothing seemed to work, nothing in logs. But eventually I cleared all caches, and it is cured. But before that I accidentally click on 'show ignored files' somewhere in git tab. Now I'm seeing them, but I cannot find this control anywhere. Project settings, pane settings ...
How to get rid of this?
(yes, .gitignore is valid, none of these files are staged, git repo is clean. This is purely idea settings)

